# TOP selection in Sybase subquery

Tags: select, sybase, sap-ase

I am trying to select all the records from a table where a certain key of this table is in a sub-selections of keys made with "TOP 10".

My query looks like this:

```
select * from FXKAUD_E_DBF events
where events.M_LINK in
(
    select top 3 header.M_LINK
    from FXKAUD_H_DBF header
    where header.M_TYPE = 1 and header.M_STATUS LIKE '%Ended successfully%'
    order by header.M_LINK desc
)
```

The inner subquery is supposed to select the top 3 values of M_LINK in the table FXKAUD_H_DBF. 
If I execute it alone, it works fine.

However, when I then try to execute the outer query (`select * from FXKAUD_E_DBF events where events.M_LINK in`) I get the following error message :

```
An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
select * from FXKAUD_E_DBF events
where events.M_LINK in
(
    select top 3 header.M_LINK
    from FXKAUD_H_DBF header
    where ...
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'top'. [SQL State=ZZZZZ, DB Errorcode=156] 

Execution time: 0s

1 statement(s) failed.
```

Does anyone have an idea? I'm running on Sybase ASE 11/12/15 - TDS 5.5.
I'd be more than happy to provide with an SQL fiddle but http://sqlfiddle.com doesn't have a Sybase engine and I only have this issue with Sybase (Oracle working fine).

Comment: While ASE supports the `top` command in derived tables, it does not support `top` in sub-queries (eg, your query); also keep in mind that ASE does not support the `order by` clause in sub-queries nor derived tables

Answer (score 0):

This is because Sybase does not support top selection in a sub-query. You need to tweak your query to get the 3 results you want in a query.